# Order by distinct elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have array of elements

Input

```
{
       "a":[1,2,3],
       "b":[4,5,6],
       "c":[7,8,9]
};
```

I want to get the elements one by one from each key.

Expected Output:

```
[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]
```

I tried following but failing in several different examples:

```
let obj = {
   "a":[1,2,3],
   "b":[4,5,6],
   "c":[7,8,9]
};
let arr = [];

for(let i in obj){
   arr.push(obj[i]);
}

let res = [];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   for(let j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++){
     res.push(arr[j][i]);
   }
}
console.log(res);
```

The above code is failing in below example:

```
{
       "a":[1,2,3]
};
```

Error: Cannot find 0 of undefined.

```
{
"a": [1,2,3],
"b": [4,5,6,7]
}
```

7 is missing in the output.

What is the best solution for the above problem.

Comment: Your code yields the exact same output that you say you want. What is the problem?

Comment: `I tried following but failing in several different examples:` what are those examples?

Comment: It might not if the order of the keys in the object is not exactly `"a", "b", "c"`. You might want to use a list of keys in their proper order rather than getting the keys from the object.

Comment: @stybl I have edited the question

Comment: `for ... in` ordering is not specified and implementation-dependant. Even with other methods, using object properties' order is highly discouraged, use a different data structure.

Comment: @SreekanthReddy What would you like to happen in cases where the arrays have different lengths? If they were `a = [1,2], b=[1,2,3,4,5], c=[1,2,3]`, should the output be `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: @stybl Yes, I need the same output as you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the max length using `Math.max` and `map` each array.

```js
let obj = {
  "a": [1, 2, 3],
  "b": [4, 5, 6, 7]
}

//Convert the object into multi dimentional array
let arr = Object.values(obj);
let res = [];


for (i = 0; i < Math.max(...arr.map(o => o.length)); i++) {  //Loop from 0 to the legnth of the longest array
  for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {                         //Loop each array
    if (arr[x][i]) res.push(arr[x][i]);                      //If element exist, push the array
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks @Eddie , but I shared the sample, they are not numbers but the objects.

Comment: @SreekanthReddy What do you mean? The variale is `obj` is an `object`. You can convert the object into array by using `Object.values()`

Comment: Got it, sorry it is working for let obj = {
  "a": [{"c": "1"},{"d": "5"}],
  "b": [{"c":"3"},{"b": "6"}]
}

Comment: Yeah, it will work if you want convert the object to array you can just use `Object.values()` :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be an another easy approach.

```js
var arr = {
       "a":[1,2,3],
       "b":[4,5,6],
       "c":[7,8,9]
};

var values = Object.values(arr); //Using this will modify the original object during the process

//In case, original object should not be modified during the process use the following
//var values = Object.values(arr).map(function(elem){return elem.slice();});

var result = [];

while(values.length)
{
    values = values.filter(function(arr,index){ return arr.length; }); //Remove the empty arrays
    result = result.concat(values.map(function(elem){ return elem.shift(); })); //Get the first element of all arrays
}

console.log(result);
```